# Prove that for a real number $a > 1$, the set $\{ a^n \}$ is unbounded from above.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that for a real number $a > 1$, the set $\{ a^1, a^2, \dots \}$ is unbounded from above.

The book I am using (Maxwell Rosenlicht's analysis) gave a hint to show that $a > 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$, which is easy since we have $a - \epsilon > 1$.

Next, they say to show that $a^n > (1+\frac{1}{n})^n \geq 2$. This is where I got stuck. How does this allow us to show that the set is unbounded from above?

Comment: What can you then say about $a^{n\cdot m}$?

Comment: $a^{nm} > 2^m$. Thanks! Some days, the brain just refuses to work. :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From $a^n \geqslant 2$ you obtain $a^{n\cdot m} \geqslant 2^m$, which is unbounded from above since $2^m > m$.

Another way to see the unboundedness is Bernoulli's inequality which shows

$$a^m \geqslant \left(1 + \frac1n\right)^m \geqslant 1 + \frac{m}{n}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Put $a = 1 + r$, where $r > 0$.  Then
$$a^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} r^k \ge 1 + rn.$$
The rest follows because the real field is archimedean.